# Multiple random UUID but value uuid is the same

Tags: scala

```
case class ConversationId(value: UUID)
case class CustomerRequestId(uuid: UUID)

class CustomerRequestReceiverController{
  def createCustomerRequest(req: Request, optConversationId: Option[ConversationId] = None): Task[Response] = {
    val NONE_REVISION = 0
    val customerRequestId = CustomerRequestId(RandomUUID.randomUUID)

    val result: Task[Response] = for {
      form <- req.as(jsonOf[CreateCustomerRequestFormInternalApiV2])
      _ = println(s"Conversation Id ${form.conversationId.getOrElse(ConversationId(RandomUUID.randomUUID))}")
      _ = appLogger.info(s"creating CustomerRequest ${form.customerId.value} with Conversation ${optConversationId.getOrElse(form.conversationId.getOrElse(RandomUUID.randomUUID))}")
      _ = logger.info(s"creating CustomerRequest ${form.customerId.value} with Conversation ${optConversationId.getOrElse(form.conversationId.getOrElse(RandomUUID.randomUUID))}")
      createCommand <- Task.delay(CreateCustomerRequest(
        customerRequestId = customerRequestId,
        communication = Communication.Chat(optConversationId.getOrElse(form.conversationId.getOrElse(ConversationId(RandomUUID.randomUUID)))),
      commandResult <- Task.delay(createCommandHandler.handle(createCommand))
      response <- responseFormat(commandResult)
    } yield response
    result.handleWith(invalidRequestBody)
  }
}
```

I expect the output of value from UUID.randomUUID() is the same UUID, but the actual output is different value

Comment: This looks like Play (though I could be wrong). Should this question also have the [tag:playframework] tag?

Answer (score 0):

Replace line

```
        customerRequestId = customerRequestId,
```

with

```
customerRequestId = CustomerRequestId(RandomUUID.randomUUID)
```

Now you generate CustomerRequestId only once and use it on each iteration